# Random unknown characters appearing in SQL database data

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Can anyone help..?

This is what is appearing in my data that I've modified using 'inline edit' in PHPMyAdmin:

��� ��� ��� ���

also Line breaks like such: `<br />` are being followed by line breaks like these: `<br>`

The symbols are appearing only when the code is rendered into a page and cannot be seen in any editing mode in PHPMyAdmin. It's the strangest thing i have ever seen.. Why would even more line breaks be written in?!

Anyone have a clue whats going on here?

This only happened after I added a new column to my table->added data in only specific entries using inline edit in phpmyadmin. These entries which I added data to, are the ones with this madness occuring.

Does anyone have an sql script that can rid my entries of white space?

This is on a localhost test server btw

Comment: need to set the database format to utf8

Comment: @nathan_hayfield utf8 what? I have many options here

Comment: probably any of them, i usually pick the first one

Comment: utf8_general is usually used.

Comment: @John - i think it's `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Hmm.. nope not working.. this happened to a 4 year old database i may add.. not a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are 16 bit (two byte) values. Each separate letter or symbol in any language is saved as a unique value. When you look at the raw data in the database, you are seeing the 8 bit (one byte) ASCII representations of the two halves of the real value. Hence, something like the two characters "Ø*" is in reality one Arabic symbol.

When MySQL outputs the information, it is converted by the two-byte values back to the proper symbols.

The same happens with any other non-European language. 8 bit ASCII has all the characters based on latin, Greek etc (many of the non-English letters are in the high order symbols; values between 0 and 127 are mostly English and the values from 128 to 255 include non-English symbols and letters). This reflects the US origins of ASCII. Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, and so many other languages have their text rendered with 16 bit values from 256 to 65384.
So - you should look up info on UTF character sets and how they are displayed.

Just create function to remove values overs 256 to remove. Every thing happens as u wanted

Comment: Seems strange that it would insert its own line breaks however. I will try to create a function first and let you know the results

Comment: Problem is solved, I will accept this answer as its very helpful, but i solved the problem by re-entering the data again.. very time consuming.